# String with special character not adding in database WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting an array from order metadata and just taking two values from that array and adding them again in the database with new meta_key

```
function custom_order_meta_tracking($order_id) {
    global $woocommerce, $post, $wpdb;
    $orderid = new WC_Order($post->ID);
  $order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $orderid->get_order_number()));
  if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $order_id, '_wc_shipment_tracking_items' )) {
      $gettracking_array = get_post_meta($order_id,'_wc_shipment_tracking_items', true);
    foreach ($gettracking_array as $key => $item ) {
        $tracking_number = $gettracking_array[$key]['tracking_number'];
        $tracking_provider = $gettracking_array[$key]['tracking_provider'];
        $tracking_providers = $wpdb->_real_escape( $tracking_provider );
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_tracking_number', $tracking_number, $prev_value);
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_tracking_provider', $tracking_providers, $prev_value);
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_order_meta_tracking', 10, 3 );
```

now the issue I am facing is that **$tracking_providers** have value with special characters like "after.ship" and in this case it did not add any value in database.

I tried **"wpdb::_real_escape"** but not working.

please help

thanks

Comment: `update_post_meta` returns `false` on error, I'd check that. Possibly turn on WordPress, PHP and MySQL error reporting.

Comment: reporting is on, and there is no error with update_post_meta because any string without any special character is going to the database smoothly, just having an issue with a sting that has "." or a special character in it.

Comment: "there is no error ... because" and "just having an issue" are partially at odds. If it isn't getting into the database, there should be an error. Can you confirm that your database it utf8mb4? If so you should be able to store pretty much everything. I can tell you that `wpdb::_real_escape` should generally be avoided, it is for very specific scenarios and this isn't one of those.